# How to remove single quotes from a string, leaving only the words(Apostrophe) ? [PhP]

Tags: php

I want to remove single quotes from a string, but not quotes that are apostrophes.

For eg:

> Please click 'here' to choose the account you'd like to Login

I need it to be like

> Please click here to choose the account you'd like to Login

I tried like this

```
$text = preg_replace( '/[^\da-z ! ?.]/i', ' ', $text );
```

But it's removing all single quotes. Any help appreciated. Didn't find any solution in stack overflow after long searches.

Comment: The english language may contain apostrophes, that are followed by a space, in case of a genitive plural noun, that ends with an 's'. Example: **the girls' dresses** [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Standardisation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern: `/\B'|'\B/`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7eqiMn/1)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d325ec6975c284c36de8f3f8a7cdef971b934ae0))

```
$text="Please click 'here' to choose the account you'd like to 'Login'";
$text = preg_replace("/\B'|'\B/",'', $text);
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
Please click here to choose the account you'd like to Login
```

---

To handle plural possessive nouns (or whatever we are calling them) like `girls' dresses`, here is a more robust call:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba34590967bfa3ba29cebdbf0cf013baa4a2e26b)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7eqiMn/4))

```
$text="Please click 'here' to choose the users' accounts that you'd like to 'use'";
$text = preg_replace("/\B'([a-z-]+)'\B/i",'$1', $text);
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
Please click here to choose the users' accounts that you'd like to use
```